# how to send whatsapp message to Paticular Contact without Click on send button

Tags: java, android

Here is my code ..

```
    String toNumber = "+91 86092 47049";
    toNumber = toNumber.replace("+", "").replace(" ", "");

    Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    sendIntent.putExtra("jid", toNumber + "@s.whatsapp.net");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello ..");
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(sendIntent);
```

It works but it's not exactly 'sending' it.It entered the text and now the
    user need to press 'send' button manually. Is it possible to send it without click on 'send' button?

Comment: Whatsapp do not allow sending text directly, user need to click on the send button to send the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [WhatsApp FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000012) there are only two ways to send text

- Using Url
- Using Intent

In both cases users have to click send button explicitly to send the message.

So as of now it is not possible to send message directly without clicking send button.

Comment: @Jayashri my pleasure.!